# How do I eliminate the repeating cases?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, similar-matrices

Let $K$ be the field with exactly $7$ elements. Let $\mathscr M$ be the set of all $2×2$ matrices with entries in $K$. How many elements of $\mathscr M$ are similar to the following matrix?

$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

My attempt: Answer is given is $56$. We need to find the cardinality of $\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} a,b,c,d\in K:a+d=1 \wedge ad=bc\}=\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 1-a
\end{pmatrix} a,b,c,d\in K: ad=bc\}.$ I got $ad=bc \implies a(1-a)=bc \implies a-a^2=bc\implies $ $a$ as a function of $bc$. So, there are $7^3$ possibilities.How do I eliminate the repeating cases?

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors? If you do you can quite quickly count that there are $(\frac{p^2 -1}{p-1})(\frac{p^2-p}{p-1})$ of them, where $p=7$.

Comment: Can you explain? What Formula is this?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I hope you meant that the two eigenvalues of the matrix matrix have distinct eigenvectors. Hence, any matrix similar to the given matrix would have its eigenvectors same upto a nonzero multiple of the eigenvectors of the given matrix, whence the formula.

Comment: also do visit the chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue as below:
$$a-a^2=bc \Longrightarrow a^2-a+bc=0 \Longrightarrow a=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4bc}}{2}\overset{1/2 = 4}{===}4\pm4\sqrt{1-4bc}$$
So $(1-4bc)$ must be square:
$$(1-4bc) \in \{ 0^2,(\pm)1^2,(\pm2)^2,(\pm3)^2 \} = \{ 0,1,4,2 \} \Longrightarrow 4bc \in \{ 1,0,-3,-1 \} \overset{1/4=2}{=\Longrightarrow}$$
$$\overset{1/4=2}{=\Longrightarrow} bc \in \{ 2,0,-6,-2 \}$$
Now we can count:
$$\begin{array}{l}
bc \overset{\text{Has 6 solutions}}{=======} {\color{white}-}2 & \Longrightarrow & a\overset{\text{Has 1 solution}}{=======}{\color{white}-}4  & \Longrightarrow & \text{Has ${\color{white}6}$6 Solutions} \\
bc \overset{\text{Has 13 solutions}}{=======} {\color{white}-}0 & \Longrightarrow & a\overset{\text{Has 2 solutions}}{=======}{\color{white}-}0,1  & \Longrightarrow & \text{Has 26 Solutions} \\
bc \overset{\text{Has 6 solutions}}{=======} -6 & \Longrightarrow & a\overset{\text{Has 2 solutions}}{=======}{\color{white}-}3,5  & \Longrightarrow & \text{Has 12 Solutions} \\
bc \overset{\text{Has 6 solutions}}{=======} -2 & \Longrightarrow & a\overset{\text{Has 2 solutions}}{=======}-1,2 & \Longrightarrow & \text{Has 12 Solutions} \\
\end{array}$$
So totally we have:
$$6+26+12+12=56 \ \text{ Solutions }$$
Also you may don't calculate $a$ and just notice the relation between "Number of solution & Sign of $\Delta$" is hold in any field.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @ancientmathematician , any matrix similar to the given matrix would have $0$ and $1$ as eigenvalues with corresponding eigenvectors similar upto a nonzero multiple of the column vectors (as they are cancelled in the inverse i.e. since $P^{-1}AP=M$). Thus, as the first and second columns of any matrix in $\mathbb{F}_p$ can be chosen in $(p^2-1)(p^2-p), p=7$ ways, therefore the desired number of eigenvectors are $\frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{(p-1)(p-1)}$ where $p=7$. Hence, the answer is $56$

Comment: I understand that the no. of matrices of $GL_{2}(F)=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ where $F$ is a field of 7 elements. But why divide by $(p-1)\times(p-1)$, I am having difficulty. If you could open an chat we could discuss about it. It will be very helpful of you.

Comment: @s1mple you can join chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72440/csir-tifr-isi-nbhm)